# Troubleshoot PHP / MSSQL connection

Tags: php, apache, logging

I have  php script that is sending values given to it to an MSSQL database.  It works about 70% of the time (there should be ~100 records, I'll see ~70).  There is no pattern, that I can see.  I am not looking for help going over the logs I already have; I need to know where I should look to find errors.  The php is simple, using mssql_query, mssql_num_rows, and mssql_fetch_array.  Timeout in php.ini has not changed from default 60s, although I have just now set it to 240s (if this fixes everything, I will update the post).  I am not able to return anything once the script has been called; every response, whether there is an error or not, must be the same.  Can I somehow log details of the mssql_query function?  Or is there a response from the SQL server I can listen for?  I've read the manual and havent seen anything like this.  Any help would be appreciated!  I need this taken care of asap.

edit - 
I can't run mssql_showlastmessage, because I can't return anything but , as things will break.  Below is the entire code.

```
<?php
//request xml cdr from switchvox
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//include switchvox libraries
require_once("SwitchvoxRequest.php");

//define sql connection stuff
$db_host = "dbhost";
$db_user = "dbuser";
$db_pass = "dbsecret";
$db = "db";
$table_sr = "tblsr";
$table_cd = "tblcmrd";
$link = mssql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
$err = "";

//make sure we can connect
if (!$link || !mssql_select_db($db, $link))
        {
            die("<response></response>");
        }

//define pbx connection stuff
$sv_host = "pbx";
$sv_user = "user";
$sv_pass = "secret";

//get the extension from the pbx and format it
$ext = $_GET['ext'];
$ext2 = $_GET['ext2'];
$jobid = $_GET['jobid'];
$et = $_GET['et'];

if(!$ext2)
        {
        $ext = substr($ext,-4,4);
        }

if(strlen($ext) > 4)
        {
        if(strlen($ext2) > 4)
                {
                die("<response></response>");
                }
        $ext = $ext2;
        }

//query the sr table to find the account ID of the extension we are referencing
$acid_sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_sr WHERE ext=$ext";
$acid_res = mssql_query($acid_sql);
$acida = mssql_fetch_array($acid_res, MSSQL_BOTH);
$acid = $acida['pbx_accountid'];

if (!$acid_res) 
        {
            die("<response></response>");
        }

//make sure there is a salesrep for the extension making the call
if (!$acid)
        {
            die("<response></response>");
        }

//get and format the time and date as YYYY-MM-DD
$date = date('Y') . "-" . date('m') . "-" . date('d');

//format the time as HH:MM:SS
$time = date('H') . ":" . date('i') . ":" . date('s');

//create a new request
$req = new SwitchvoxRequest($sv_host, $sv_user, $sv_pass);
$reqpar = array
        (
        'account_ids' => array
                (
                'account_id' => array
                        (
                        $acid
                        )
                ),
            'start_date' => array
                (
                $date . " " . "00:00:00"
                ),
        'end_date' =>  array
                (
                $date . " " . $time
                ),
        'sort_field' => array
                (
                ),
        'sort_order' => array
                (
                'DESC'
                )
        );
$res = $req -> send("switchvox.callLogs.search", $reqpar);
$result = $res->getResult();
$calls = $result['calls']['total_items'];

//check that there were calls to/from this account today
if(!$calls)
        {
        die("<response></response>");
        }

$latest = $result['calls']['call']['0'];
$callid = $latest['id'];

//check to see if the call has already been logged
$id_sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_cd WHERE callID='$callid'";
$id_res = mssql_query($id_sql);
$exid = mssql_fetch_array($id_res, MSSQL_ASSOC);

if (!$id_res) 
        {
    die("<response></response>");
        }

if($exid['callID'])
        {
        die("<response></response>");
        }

//define variables to be sent to the table
$from = $latest['from_number'];
$to = $latest['to_number'];
$durat = $latest['talk_duration'];
$start = $latest['start_time'];
$callid = $latest['id'];
$calltype = $latest['origination'];

//check the length of the cid/ext strings and swap if needed
if (strlen($from) > strlen($to))
        {
        $extension = $to;
        $phonenumber = $from;
        }
        else
        {
        $extension = $from;
        $phonenumber = $to;
        }

//insert the data into the table
$fi_sql = "INSERT INTO $table_cd (extension, phonenumber, calldatetime, duration, callID, calltype)     VALUES ($extension, $phonenumber, '$start', '$durat', '$callid', '$calltype')";
$fi_res = mssql_query($fi_sql);

if (!$fi_res) 
{
    die("<response></response>");
}

$sv_res = "<response></response>";

echo $sv_res;
?>
```

I realize this is open to sql injections.  That's ok.

edit -

I looked through the logs on the database; there are no errors for when I would expect there to have been data inserted, nothing even indicating that it tried.  I am going to look at something that will log messages to syslog or something from php.  suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: Try mssql_get_last_message() after every DB call to see if you get something useful?

Comment: `The php is simple, using mssql_query, mssql_num_rows, and mssql_fetch_array.` then show us the code...

Comment: You said: "I can't run mssql_showlastmessage, because I can't return anything but , as things will break." Things are already broken so I don't see that you have a choice. You need to find out what's wrong, and the error message will tell you.

Comment: At that point, I don't know if things are broken because I am adding things that shouldnt be there, or for another reason.  Responding with anything but "<response></response>" results in "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are free to execute this on MySQL

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

to get a **description of a SELECT statement**. This feature basically explains, how MySQL's query analyzer sees your query and how it would be executed. For example, `EXPLAIN` describes, if MySQL is about to perform costly table-scans or may use an index and if so, which one.

Are you sure, that MySQL is causing the problem? Or might PHP force problems?

Do you check [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after each query?

Is $ext probably not numeric? In this case, $ext should get quoted (sorry, don't like variable substitution inside of string):

```
$acid_sql = "SELECT * FROM " .  $table_sr . " WHERE ext='" . $ext . "'";
```

Since you return XML and if the client of this routine behaves well, why not insert a new element inside of response like this:

```
<response>
   ... other elements ...
  <sysInfo>
    Failed to perform...
  </sysInfo>
</response>
```

A well-behaving XML client should only read known elements and thus skip additional elements. Adding such a logic return code always useful.

**PS:** Although the above code might just be a sample, let me remark, that it is attackable by **sql-injections**.

Comment: I dont think any of the queries I am running are taxing the database to a point where it can't continue send a result...Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Explain describes, how costly these queries are. MySQL will always return result. In case you have problem, you should probably check MySQL slowQuery counter.

Comment: I am using MS sql.  And having checked the sql server logs, there are no errors or anything during the periods where data wasnt inserted.

Comment: $ext will be a 4 digit number, always.

Comment: OK, then, without an option to trace debug information, I don't see a simple way to fix the problem. Why not create a new table to log messages of this routine?

Comment: I dont have control of the database.  I actually tried what you suggested earlier, by adding an error element to the response, but I was still having issues, and again, can't say for certain what is causing them.  I think I need to log errors to syslog or similar.